# Chagas disease: transmission

Tags: disease-transmission

I am reading about Chagas disease. It is not clear for me if the transmission from mother to child can be called *vector transmission* or not, because I read in wikipedia that:

> In Chagas-endemic areas, the main mode of transmission is through an
>   insect vector called a triatomine bug

So, main mode of transmission is through the vector but from mother to child is also a less common mode of transmission?

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mother-to-Child transmission is known as "vertical transmission". Vector transmission exclusively refers to an intermediate organism (often, but not always, an insect).